# Printing an ASCII table

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I wrote this code in C to print the ASCII table, but I was told to use SML for this specific task

Here is my current code in C:

```
// Program to print ASCII table.

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char count;
    for(count=32; count< 255; count+=1)
    {
        printf("  %3d - %c",count,count);
        if(count % 6==0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How would I go about doing this in SML? I scoured the internet but with no luck!

Comment: SO is not a free code translation service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include both the original code and your effort to convert it, and ask a specific question related to that code, and we can try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about doing this in SML?

First off, you would learn SML. ;-)

- Instead of `for(count=32; count< 255; count+=1)` you might use [`List.tabulate`](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.tabulate:VAL).
- In SML `printf` is considered a [big gun](http://mlton.org/Printf), so perhaps stick to `print`.
- Instead of `%c` you can use `str` and `chr`, e.g. `str (chr 65) = "A"`
- Instead of `%03d` you do get `Int.toString`, but you have to make your own `pad` function, yay!
- For applying a function `f` to every element of a list and discard the return values (which makes sense if you're interested in only the side-effects of `f`), you can use `List.app` rather than `List.map`.

A template for getting started is:

```
val table = List.tabulate (256 - 32, fn count => str (chr (count + 32)))
val _ = List.app (fn cstr => print "Ceci n'est pas une ASCII table\n") table
```

Try and make a reasonable attempt to solve this task and provide an answer to your own StackOverflow question.